# How to fix the UTF-8 character encoded filenames which don't look good in sub directories

Tags: character-encoding

I have filenames like `KÃ¤yttÃ¶ohje.pdf`. This should be `Käyttöohje.pdf`.

I can do the conversion of all files in sub directories with the command:

```
convmv -f utf8 -t iso-8859-1 -r --notest *
```

This converts `KÃ¤yttÃ¶ohje.pdf` to `Käyttöohje.pdf`.

The problem is if the file is already in form `Käyttöohje.pdf`

File `Käyttöohje.pdf` is converted to `K'$'\344''ytt'$'\366''ohje.pdf`

How to change the above command so that

- `Käyttöohje.pdf` is converted to `Käyttöohje.pdf` (left alone) and
- `KÃ¤yttÃ¶ohje.pdf` is still converted to `Käyttöohje.pdf`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your incorrect files appear to be double-UTF-8 encoded.

For instance, the `ä` U+00E4 has been encoded as:

1. U+00E4 -> 0xc3 0xa4 (UTF-8 encoding)
2. 0xc3 -> 0xc3 0x83 (iso8859-1 `Ã` -> UTF-8), 0xa4 -> 0xc3 0xa4 (iso8859-1 `¤` -> UTF-8) where each byte of the UTF-8 encoding of U+00E4 has been interpreted as if they were the encoding of some other character in a single-byte charset (here likely iso8859-1 or windows-1252) and encoded again in UTF-8.

So you're right to use `convmv -f utf8 -t iso-8859-1` for that. To leave the files that are not double-encoded alone, `convmv` has a special option for that: `--fixdouble`, so it should just be:

```
convmv --fixdouble -f utf8 -t iso-8859-1 -r --notest .
```

There's a section dedicated to that in [`convmv`'s manual](https://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/man/):

> ### How to undo double UTF-8 (or other) encoded filenames
>
> Sometimes it might happen that you "double-encoded" certain filenames, for example the file names already were UTF-8 encoded and you
> accidentally did another conversion from some charset to UTF-8. You can simply undo that by converting that the other way round. The
> from-charset has to be UTF-8 and the to-charset has to be the from-charset you previously accidentlly used.  If you use the
> "--fixdouble" option convmv will make sure that only files will be processed that will still be UTF-8 encoded after conversion and it
> will leave non-UTF-8 files untouched. You should check to get the correct results by doing the conversion without "--notest" before,
> also the "--qfrom" option might be helpful, because the double utf-8 file names might screw up your terminal if they are being printed -
> they often contain control sequences which do funny things with your terminal window. If you are not sure about the charset which was
> accidentally converted from, using "--qfrom" is a good way to fiddle out the required encoding without destroying the file names finally.

Files that are double-UTF-encoded via iso8859-1 (which covers code points U+0000 U+00FF) will contain sequences of non-ASCII characters consisting of one character in the  the U+00C2 -> U+00F4 range (`ÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóô`) followed by one or more characters in the U+0080 -> U+00BF range (U+0080 to U+009F being control character plus non-breaking space plus `¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿`). Those sequences are relatively unlikely to occur in non-double-encoded text, especially considering that characters above U+00E0 (the lower case ones in the first set above) have to be followed by at least 2 characters in the second set, so `convmv --fixdouble` is unlikely to get it wrong.